# Is it possible to modify properties of multiple objects or class instances all at once with one line of code?

Tags: javascript, class, object, destructuring, es6-class

In JavaScript (assuming version is >= ES6), say that I have a class;

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.property = null;
  }
}
```

... and I create two new instances of the class;

```
let inst1 = new MyClass(), inst2 = new MyClass();
```

Now, say I want `inst1` and `inst2`'s `property` value to `true`. This can be easily accomplished with

```
inst1.property = true;
inst2.property = true;
```

However, if I end up with many instances, reassigning each and every value, a new line each time, the code can get out of hand;

```
inst1.property = true;
inst2.property = true;
inst3.property = true;
inst4.property = true;
// ...
```

Now, I know, this is a very bad example, but you can just imagine a better example in its place. I wanted to know if there was any way to modify multiple instances with only one line of code, through something similar to object destructuring. For example,

```
[inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4].property = true;
```

I apologize if this is a bad question, but I just noticed my code getting messy with a scenario similar to this, and wondered if there was a solution to it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no automatic way to affect very instance of a class.  You could have the constructor automatically add an instance to a master Set and then you'd have an ability to iterate all instances via that Set.  But ... be very careful doing that because it defeats garbage collection entirely unless you manually remove instances that are no longer needed from the master Set object.

Comment: If you're going to manually list the instances, you can do this in one line: `[inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4].forEach(el => {el.property = true;})`.  You may also find a helper function to be useful.

Comment: Just use a loop?

Comment: "*I know, this is a very bad example, but you can just imagine a better example in its place.*" - actually I cannot imagine an example where you are creating a lot of instances without placing them in an array (or other collection) instead of storing them in separate variables.

Comment: If you want this to happen to really **all** instances, then it should not be an instance property. You can use a property on the prototype, or a static field.

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner where you manually list the instances:

```
[inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4].forEach(el => {el.property = true;})
```

But, if you really want all instances to have the same value for that propery, then perhaps it shouldn't be an instance variable and could just be a static property (a property on the class) that every instance can refer to.

Comment: you don't need curvy brackets here

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You do, to signify that you don't want to return anything

Comment: @Bergi i see....

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with static methods that would collect a class' instances' weak references and update their props, than you can reuse it with any of your classes:

```js
class InstanceCollection{
  static instances = [];
  static updateProperties(props){
    const instances = InstanceCollection.instances;
    for(const prop in props){
      for(let i = 0; i < instances.length; i++){
        const instance = instances[i].deref();
        instance ? (instance[prop] = props[prop]) : instances.splice(i--, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  static addInstance(instance){
    InstanceCollection.instances.push(new WeakRef(instance));
  }
}


class MyClass extends InstanceCollection{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.property = null;
    MyClass.addInstance(this);
  }
}

let inst1 = new MyClass(), inst2 = new MyClass(), inst3 = new MyClass(), inst4 = new MyClass();

MyClass.updateProperties({property: true});

console.log(inst1, inst2, inst3, inst4);
```

Comment: This is leaking memory if you never call `updateProperties`

Comment: @Bergi why? could you explain?

Comment: Well it's leaking `WeakRef` instances in the ever-growing array

Comment: @Bergi i know. i found it minor.